# Textcontext property in MStest giving null reference exeption

Tags: mstest, testcontext

I am trying to create a Unit test project in Visual studio 2017 . I want to use Testcontext class prorperties like TestName and etc in my test class and Test method . But when i run the project in debug mode i get null object reference for Testcontext object .

Below is the code :

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject2
{

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private TestContext _testcontext;
        public  TestContext Testcontext
        {
            get { return _testcontext; }
            set { _testcontext = value; }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Testcontext.TestName);
        }
    }    
}
```

I am not able to find out how to fix this problem using Coded UI project it works fine.

the exception

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the definition for TestContext property.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject2 
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Testcontext.TestName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: using System;

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject2
{

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
       // private TestContext _testcontext;
        public  TestContext Testcontext
        {
            get;
            set;


        }

        
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod2()
        {


            Console.WriteLine(Testcontext.TestName);
        }

        
 
    }

    
}

Comment: My example said `TestContext` not `Testcontext`. Did you try exactly as I wrote the code?

Comment: Yes , it worked thanks a lot . But I did not get logic why TestContext will work and why Testcontext will not . Both are of type TestContext class .

Comment: I think mstest uses reflection + case sensitive string comparison to manually set the property value. I had the same problem myself so I knew what would have worked here.

Comment: i m uisng vs2017 /nunit3 and followed as mentioned above but it returns null

Comment: @Salman That answer specifically applies to mstest, as per the question tag. You will need to search or ask a new question for nunit.

Comment: @TanveerBadar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58768812/testcontext-property-is-null . any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set value for the `_testcontext` in the code sample you have provided so you will get `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: i have set it - check this  piece of code in the initial question                                                        private TestContext _testcontext;
        public  TestContext Testcontext
        {
            get { return _testcontext; }
            set { _testcontext = value; }
        }