# TestContext property is null

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nunit-3.0

i have been tryign to get current test directory from where tests are running. 
code that i m using

```
[TestFixture]
    public class ValidatePDF
    {
        public NUnit.Framework.TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
 [SetUp]
        public void Init()
        {
           string t = TestContext.TestDirectory;
        }
}
```

TestContext is always null. 
i m using Visual Studio 2017 , and NUnit 3 
i have tried with MS TextContext but it always return null

```
public Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext TestContext { get; set; } 

 [Test]
    public void GetMetaInfo()
    {
        string t = TestContext.TestDir;           
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the MS TestContext, and use NUnit's built in TestContext.  Note that it is a static property, so access the CurrentContext's members.

[image]